# applying filters in pandas using jupyter, but no records are there only headers are showing

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

This is the table details from where I am looking for the data.

[image]

This is what the output I am getting after applying the filter only the headers.

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would happen if there are no rows matching your criteria.

Try changing the 'isin' list to include something you are certain should return at least one row, so we can test the filtering step.